# Substring and Charindex using SSIS

Tags: ssis

File Name

```
||N:\Health\Local\Information\Tec\IS\Exports\MM\ADQ star pu\H and A ADQ April.csv || 
N:\Health\Local\Information\Tec\IS\Exports\MM\ADQ star pu\Vita April.csv

Update [MM].[dbo].[Star]
SET [Query Name]=
SUBSTRING([File Name], LEN(File Name) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(File Name)) + 2, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(File Name)) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(File Name)) - 1)
```

I am using the query above in a Execute SQL Task which retrieves "H and A ADQ" and "Vita" in a field called "Query Name" but now I want to carry out the process in SSIS using Derived Column. Can anyone help?

Comment: what version of ssis?

Answer (score 1):

For SUBSTRING, you already have a similar function for derived column. Instead of CharIndex use -

```
FINDSTRING( «character_expression», «string», «occurrence» )
```

Here is how you would write it ... just replace the string of the file name with your column name.

```
SUBSTRING("N:\\Health\\Local\\Information\\Tec\\IS\\Exports\\MM\\ADQ star pu\\H and A ADQ April.csv", 
LEN("N:\\Health\\Local\\Information\\Tec\\IS\\Exports\\MM\\ADQ star pu\\H and A ADQ April.csv") - FindString(REVERSE("N:\\Health\\Local\\Information\\Tec\\IS\\Exports\\MM\\ADQ star pu\\H and A ADQ April.csv"), "\\" ,1) + 2, 
FINDSTRING(REVERSE("N:\\Health\\Local\\Information\\Tec\\IS\\Exports\\MM\\ADQ star pu\\H and A ADQ April.csv"), "\\" ,1) - FINDSTRING(REVERSE("N:\\Health\\Local\\Information\\Tec\\IS\\Exports\\MM\\ADQ star pu\\H and A ADQ April.csv"), " " , 1) - 1)
```

Assuming your column name is [File Name]
The expression would be -

```
SUBSTRING([File Name], 
 LEN([File Name]) - FindString(REVERSE([File Name]), "\\" ,1) + 2, 
 FINDSTRING(REVERSE([File Name]), "\\" ,1) - FINDSTRING(REVERSE([File Name]), " " , 1) - 1)
```

Comment: The Derived Columns doesn't seem to like it. I get an error. This is what I put in the derived Column based on your workings. SUBSTRING([File Name], LEN([File Name]) - Findstring(REVERSE([File Name]),"\",1)+2, FINDSTRING(REVERSE([File Name]), " ", 1)-1).

Comment: Typically if you hover with your mouse pointer over the expression in red it shows you the error. In what you have pasted I see that you have used "\" without the escape character which might be one of the problems. Answer updated with your column name.